# Filemaker to Filemaker database Import Table issue

Tags: database, import, filemaker

I have one filemaker database for my own use that I update regularly from a second filemaker database (which is active everyday).

I have a simple script that imports all data from active database into my own database. Both database are identical - just differ in records.

The problem I have is for tables which are used as portals. This data, when imported, shows the correct number of rows but only as duplicates of the last row.

This is my import script:
http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8165/7351115686_d7efbac90e_b.jpg

And this is the original table (left) and the table on my database after import (right):
http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7229/7351115740_c6677dfee5_b.jpg

Has totally thrown me - what am I doing wrong?
any help will be hugely appreciated,

Best
Steve

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're matching based on the foreign key, not the primary key. when you use the foreign it's matching as it iterates thru the lines and the last one is the one that stays.

Comment: Perfect - that did solve it. Many thanks (apologies for the late feedback) :)